# Why performSelector:withObject:afterDelay works even if the app is in background?

Tags: ios, xcode, background, performselector

Im not using any special background-mode. I've created this simple project:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(callservice) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}

-(void) callservice
{
    NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                          returningResponse:&response
                                                      error:&error];
    if (error == nil)
    {
        // Parse data here
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(callservice) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}

@end
```

When I press "Home Button" ,  the app goes to background.  At this point, I opened Charles for tracking requests and I noticed the app still calls "www.google.com" every 5 seconds. (I know that at the end of callservice method I'm calling again `performselector:withobject:afterdelay`, but I thought going to background will stop it as I'm not using any background mode).I waited for 10 minutes and the app still make requests.
Since that, I thought that after pressing "Home" in simulator, the app was still awake as was running with Xcode. So I stopped the app from Xcode and run it from the simulator directly. The requests still remain.
Why that happens?  `performselector:withobject:afterdelay` awakes the app every 5 seconds?
For how long iOS keep the app awake when pressing "Home"?
Thanks!

Comment: Tested with device, and works as expected. When going to background, the requests stop.